# Add EF 6.x EntityObject Generator in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017, objectcontext

We are planning to switch to Visual Studio 2017.
For our Entity Framework 6 edmx file we use the [EntityObject Generator extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EF6xEntityObjectGeneratorforC) to create us the desired ObjectContext.

This extension is only compatible up to VS2013 - [inofficially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823159/how-to-add-entityobject-generator-in-visual-studio-2015) up to VS2015. The solution to simply adjust the manifest file in the vsix does not seem to work for VS2017 though - I guess among others because the vsix architecture changed.

Is there a way to get the ObjectContext template without using an old Visual Studio? I assume the template is not always the same for each edmx file so it could simply be copy pasted from an existing project.

Comment: You really should consider moving away from ObjectContext and refactor your code to DbContext. Really, you shouldn't be using ObjectContext anymore.

Comment: I know... But I fear this won't be so easy. But certainly worth being discussed.

Comment: I did it a couple of years ago in a large application. It wasn't really that hard. Make sure to have ample regression tests in place and go for it.

Answer (score 3):

I just did this in VS2017.

Download the VS extension package "EF 6.x EntityObject Generator for C#" from MS. It's a *.VSIX file. Rename it to ZIP. open the zip file and inside that you find one more zip.
There you will see a TT file. Copy it out.

In your project that have a MyModel.TT file that generates DbSet just replace that TT file with the one you got from vsix file.

Edit one line:

```
    SourceCsdlPath = @"$edmxInputFile$",
```

to your

```
    SourceCsdlPath = @"myEDM.emdx",
```

save TT file and your c# model code is generated with old EntityObjects