# How to use EF 6.x EntityObject Generator in VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, edmx

I have to use EF6.x EntityObjectGenerator.vsix with VS 2017, but the vsix is not working with VS2017. Please let me know if someone has used ?
I tried updating manifest file by adding visual studio version for VS2017. After doing so, it started showing the manifest file is corrupted. Please help me how could I use EntityObjectGenerator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241084/add-ef-6-x-entityobject-generator-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241084/add-ef-6-x-entityobject-generator-in-visual-studio-2017 - I followed this, and it answered my issue.